# Mesoamerican and Giza's Pyramids

Tags: ancient-egypt, egypt, mesoamerica, pyramids

I am not a history major but I am very interested in Pyramids and their origin.

Is there any theory that says Mesoamerican and Giza's pyramids were build before continental drift ?? If so, can you briefly write about them?

Thank you,

Apologies if the question doesn't meet the requirement of this forum. 
All I want to know if anybody ever proposed/rejected pseudo scientific theories like this. If so have such theories and their disprove ever been published in academic journals?

Comment: Have you done any preliminary research at all?

Comment: I did enough research. And as I mentioned, I'm not a history major. I don't know what kind of literature to look at to find different theories on Egyptology. So why not asking a history forum full of professionals?? I understand that the question asked might be against the regulation of the forum and wasn't stated correctly. And I am sorry that the question sounds stupid to most of you guys (and I get Negative points LOL). But there can be a "stupid theory" from maybe 100 years ago and someone probably proved it wrong like in all fields!!! If I want to know that where and who should I ask?

Comment: maybe the problem then is you are not sure how to do the research - fair enough, sometimes that is difficult. If I were researching this, I would first google 'continental drift' to get an idea of date & theories. Then I would google 'pyramids' for similar info. The huge difference in dates makes it highly unlikely that anyone would propose such a theory as it can easily be destroyed. Alien theories are much more popular, partly because lack of evidence is not evidence in itself (i.e. difficult to actually disprove).

Comment: Yes, these kind of topics are rather pseudo scientific and once again I shouldn't have posted here. Yet I still don't see why such a theory can be easily destroyed but alien theory possibly can be approved. "Huge difference in dates" between the events can't be a reason for superiority of one over another.

Comment: There weren't any humans around when the continents were joined so anyone proposing such a theory would just be ignored. Alien theories flourish because we can't prove that aliens haven't visited earth so, however bizarre those theories are, some people will choose to believe them without any proof whatsoever. Taking a more cynical view, there's also money to be made in alien theories (book publishing, ads on videos etc).

Comment: Well, If someone talks pseodoscience then he/she might also argue that humans lived at that period as well. Yes, that is so true. The idea of aliens is somewhat "cool" and people easily accept it. All these theories and how they evolve are so fascinating. Like until recently I thought oldest human fossil that they found is no more than 3million years, but scientists in Canada found 7 million years old human fossils.

Answer (score 3):

No. That is impossible. [Continental drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_drift) is a geological phenomena millions, if not billions of years, in progress.

You probably wonder why those constructions look fairly similar. Mesoamericans and Egyptians both discovered *independent of each other* that stacking stones that way is very durable.

Comment: Not only that, I was curious about the alignment and precision of other historical structures such as Machupichu, Ollantayatambo, heads in eastern island , etc. and how did humans built them across thousands of miles and with such precision....?

Comment: @Racaio Cmoto Try googling the structures you are interested in. Wikipedia should cover these in some detail. If you still have a question after looking at these articles, you ask it here but make sure you include details on the research you have done and why the articles haven't solved your problem.

Comment: They actually aren't particularly similar either. The ones in Mesoamerica are step-pyramids, not smooth-sided pyramids like most of the ones in Egypt.

Comment: @T.E.D. I fully agree. But that isn't what most people think. They read 'pyramid' and that is the pointy Egyptian thingy. Therefore, step pyramids must be pointy thingies too. As they are on 2 different continents, aliens must have helped them. :-)

Comment: @LarsBosteen My first try was google scholar for possible/rejected theories on pyramids and continental drift etc..., ended up unsuccessful. That's why I asked the question to see if there is literature on such theory (regardless of its validity).

Comment: @Jos , If you read carefully nobody talked about shape of pyramid and its being pointy or no!!!
ALIGNMENT and geographic location has always been a question. Some even argued that continental drift is the most likely explanation for the general alignment 4 minutes west of north... 
I am impressed with your certainty on answers to the subject, no doubt you know more than me in this field, but I also expect you to be more serious and respond professionally.

Comment: @T.E.D. well there are step pyramids in Egypt as well.

Comment: Yes, also adobe houses. What's your point? Aliens did it?

Comment: @Jos,  What aliens sir???? What do you mean by "also adobe houses"???? my point is when you respond be clear, serious and don't misinterpret what people say, nobody said "Aliens did it".

Comment: @RaicaioCmoto Pseudo scientific theories are not accepted here. There are other groups for it. Your question if continental drift was involved is borderline already. You could have found that easily on Google. There is no debate at all about the relation step-pyramids vs Egyptian pyramids. The first Egyptian pyramids were step-pyramids. Why? Because they are much easier to build. I call it a day now. This has gone far enough to my liking.

Comment: `Some even argued that continental drift is the most likely explanation for the general alignment 4 minutes west of north` As explained, the time scales of continental drift make it meaningless to explain any historical event; the map 10.000 years ago is basically the same map as today, and variations are minor and due to erosion and deposit of sediments. And the idea of some kind of relationship `across thousands of miles and with such precision` falls well into pseudo-science.